# Convert image color space to RGB in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, color-space

I'm working on the image processing script(`Python` with `PIL` library) and i need to convert color space of any image to `RGB`. I've tried this trick, but it works only with `png` images in `RGBa` color space:

```
image = Image.open(imageFile)
image.load()

# replace alpha channel with white color
self.im = Image.new('RGB', image.size, (255, 255, 255))
self.im.paste(image, mask=image.split()[3])
```

How to make this code universally to all images in any colorspace?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution:

```
image = Image.open(imageFile)
image.load()

# replace alpha channel with white color
self.im = Image.new('RGB', image.size, (255, 255, 255))
self.im.paste(image, None)
```

in the `self.im` variable will be stored an image in RGB colorspace with white(255, 255, 255) alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to use PIL? I would suggest the openCV version 2 python bindings `cv2`

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cv2.cvtColor

It has many possible conversions between the most common colourspaces.

If you dont want `openCV` you can use `skimage`

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#convert-colorspace

Comment: Would you happen to know if skimage xyz2rgb( lab2xyz( lab )) is sane for lab out-of-gamut ?